# Compare results of more than two ordinal models with different IVs

Tags: r, regression, ordinal-data

I am using the `ordinal` package to create 4 different ordinal/cumulative link models. The dependent variable is a ranking (1, 2, 3, 4, or 5) and the independent variable is a different model score for each. My four models look like:

```
library(ordinal)
clm(opinion ~ linear.model.score)
clm(opinion ~ normalized.linear.model.score)
clm(opinion ~ log.model.score)
clm(opinion ~ normalized.log.model.score)
```

How can I compare all 4 models? I am trying to determine which version of my model's score makes the most consistent predictions, i.e. a higher model score consistently correlates to a higher opinion score. The model score doesn't have any bounds, though practically the linear score would be between 0 and ~100.

I am normalizing by the number of words in a test sentence, so the normalizing factor stays the same. In the log version, I am just taking the natural log of each model score. In addition, the model score is based on a handful of lexical factors. The opinion score just comes from an experiment.

Comment: On what basis do you want to compare them??

Comment: I want to say which model provides the best prediction of opinion scores. Does that make sense, or is that still too ambiguous?

Comment: It helps, but how do you plan to measure the prediction quality?

Comment: It would likely be a correlation, so whichever model consistently generates a higher (continuous) score for a higher (ordinal) opinion score.

Comment: *Which* correlation coefficient would you use?  And, since (presumably) your `clm` model (whatever it might be) is actually producing a probability distribution of outcomes, how will you use that to compute the correlation?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I am understanding all of those questions. Would you mind expanding on them?

Comment: Can you correct your post title and content to remove the incorrect reference to *linear models*? The clm() function in the **ordinal** package of R does NOT fit *linear models* for continuous response variables; it fits *cumulative link models* for ordinal response variables. In R, linear models would be fitted with the lm() function.

Comment: Sure. Is it more proper now?

Comment: To get meaningful responses for your question, you will need to explain more about your response variable and predictors, in particular the difference among your various predictors.  Also, why do you really want to compare your four models? Is it because you are trying to determine which of your predictors is most suitable for your purposes? Because you are trying to determine which model is the best? Because you are trying to determine which model has the best predictive performance? Your answer to these questions will determine the most appropriate approach.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, Adam! The model terminology is appropriate now. Previously, it was incorrect and hence misleading.  Now all you need to do is add more information about your response and predictor variables and the purpose of your model comparisons. This information will help people on this forum provide answers to your question.

Comment: Thanks @IsabellaGhement. Does the edit provide sufficient details?

Comment: Yes, much better. Still not clear how you get your model scores. Do those come from a different model?

Comment: Yes. The model is based on lexical factors. The opinion scored just come from an experiment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for all your clarifications, Adam. If you are willing to use R's **rms** package instead of the **ordinal** package, you can fit your models using the *lrm()* function. For example:

```
library("rms")

# proportional odds model
model1 <- lrm(opinion ~ linear.model.score, x = TRUE, y = TRUE)

# ordinal model summary
summary(model1)

# ordinal anova
anova(model1)
```

The **rms** package will produce *discrimination indexes* (e.g., $R^2$) and *rank discrimination indexes* for the model, (e.g., $C$) evaluated on the data at hand, which can be used as a basis for comparing predictive performance across models.

Because you will use your models for predictive purposes, you have to validate the models (preferably, using bootstrap) before you consider comparing them in terms of any of the indexes described above. As stated by E.W. Steyerberg in the chapter *Overfitting and optimism in prediction models* of the book **Clinical Prediction Models** (https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-77244-8_5):

*"A key threat to validity is overfitting, i.e. that the data under study are well described, but that predictions are not valid for new subjects. Overfitting causes optimism about a model's performance in new subjects."*

In other words, models can perform well on the data at hand, but not necessarily on new data. Validation will produce optimism-corrected versions of all indexes.  You can compare these optimism-corrected versions for your chosen indexes. For example:

```
set.seed(132)

val1 <- validate(model1, method = "boot", B = 200) 

val1
```

will perform bootstrap validation of your first model using B = 200 bootstrap samples.

Discrimination is only one aspect of predictive performance; the other one is calibration.  Simple calibration statistics reported by the *validate()* function (i.e., calibration slope and intercept) do not address the issue of whether predicted values from the model are miscalibrated in a nonlinear - rather than linear - way. You can estimate and visualize an optimism-corrected calibration curve nonparametrically via the commands:

```
set.seed(132)

cal1 <- calibrate(model1, method = "boot", B = 200)

plot(cal1)
```

Dr. Frank Harrell's book on **Regression Modelling Strategies** (2nd Edition) will include all the information you need on model fitting, validation, diagnostics and presentation of model results using the **rms** package.

**Addendum:**

You could pick the model which provides the best performance across most of the indexes reported by **rms**.  This way, you don't have to choose a single index (since different indexes quantify different aspects of model performance and they all have limitations).

However,if you had to choose one optimism-corrected discrimination index, perhaps go for Somers' Dxy rank correlation?

The optimism-corrected calibration intercept should be close to 0 and the optimism-corrected calibration slope should be close to 1. If they are not, penalizing the model might help.

The optimism-corrected calibration curve should be 'close' to the 45-degree line (that is, the line with an intercept of 0 and a slope of 1).

Comment: Wow this is an incredible answer. Thank you so much. Which metric should I actually use for model comparison?

Comment: I inserted an Addendum at the end of my answer. You should read up on the various indexes reported by validate() to make sure you end up focusing on the one(s) most appropriate for your purposes.